# SSRS - remove the need for login when displaying reports

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I am working on an MVC application that displays SSRS reports (among aother things).
The basic use case for these reports is that the user logins to the system, works for a while, and then views some reports.
the reports are refferenced thus:

```
<object class="reportsObject" type="text/html"
    data="url_to_the_report">
</object>
```

the report should then be displayed within the application, and the user can play around with filters and generate it. 
the thing is - before the report is displayed, the user is prompted for another login (this time to SSRS). the user then need to insert the same credentials he\she entered when logging in to the application - and that is the thing I want to avoid.
Is there any way for me to tell SSRS: "this user is ok, he is with me - let him in"?
Do i need to change the way the report is embeded?

I have read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cliffgreen/archive/2011/03/29/reporting-services-single-sign-on-sso-authentication-part-1.aspx) article, and the main idea seems like what i need, though the implementation doesn't seem to aplly to the way i'm embeding the report.
if i'm wrong - could someone please explain how i can use this tecnique in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the reportviewer web control for this?

https://www.google.nl/search?newwindow=1&tbs=qdr%3Ay&q=report+viewer+web+control+mvc&oq=report+viewer+web+control+mvc&gs_l=serp.3...17513.18800.0.19106.4.4.0.0.0.0.85.264.4.4.0....0...1c.1.55.serp..2.2.156.V1q67x1SjbA